# Java Beginner: Generating Random Colors in Recursion

Tags: java

Hi I just started taking a Java course so this is probably a very stupid question but hopefully someone is willing to help! I'm having issues understanding how to implement a random color generating code into this recursive squares code. (We're using the Princeton course Std library )I've been trying to add certain ones such as:

```
public Color randomColor()
{
  Random random=new Random(); 
  int red=random.nextInt(256);
  int green=random.nextInt(256);
  int blue=random.nextInt(256);
  return new Color(red, green, blue);
}
```

but I don't know how to call it in my code below to change it from Stdlib's light gray to random colours.

```
public class Exercise5 {


public static void drawSquare(double x, double y, double size) {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.LIGHT_GRAY);
    StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, size/2);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.square(x, y, size/2);
}


public static void draw(int n, double x, double y, double size) {
    if (n == 0) return;

    drawSquare(x, y, size);


    double ratio = 2.2;


    draw(n-1, x - size/2, y - size/2, size/ratio);    // lower left  
    draw(n-1, x - size/2, y + size/2, size/ratio);    // upper left  
    draw(n-1, x + size/2, y - size/2, size/ratio);    // lower right 
    draw(n-1, x + size/2, y + size/2, size/ratio);    // upper right
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int n = 6;
        double x = 0.5, y = 0.5;   // center of square
    double size = 0.5;         // side length of square
    draw(n, x, y, size);
}

}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Thank you :)

Comment: Are you wondering how to use `randomColour()` instead of `StdDraw.LIGHT_GRAY`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your other methods are `static`, you'll need to make your `randomColor()` method `static` as well.

Then you can use `StdDraw.setPenColor(randomColor());` to set a random pen color, or if you want to be more explicit:

```
Color rand = randomColor();
StdDraw.setPenColor(rand);
```